# Accessing a nested class member from another nested class (C++)

Tags: c++, nested

I have a class `Enclosing`, that contains `PImpl` class.
The declaration of the `Enclosing` is in `all_includes.h` file and it's definition is in `enclosing.cpp`. I can not change that. `PImpl` is defined in `enclosing.h`.

I want to add a `Nested` class into the `Enclosing` and I want to be able to access from it a member of a `PImpl`.
Is that even possible?

For now I can not access `Enclosing::Nested` from main.
I tried different configurations of where to declare and define `Nested`, but I didn't manage to do it so it works.

The code:

all_includes.h

```
#ifndef _TVG_ALL_INCLUDES_H_
#define _TVG_ALL_INCLUDES_H_

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Enclosing
{
  int _e;
  Enclosing(int i);
 
  class PImpl;
  PImpl* _p;
 
  class Nested;
  Nested fun();
};

#endif
```

enclosing.cpp

```
#include "enclosing.h"
#include <iostream>


Enclosing::Enclosing(int i) : _e{i}, _p{new PImpl(2*i)}
{
  cout << "Enclosing constr: " << _e << endl;
}


Enclosing::Nested Enclosing::fun()
{
  cout << "returns Enc::Nest " << endl;
  return Enclosing::Nested(0, nullptr);
}
```

enclosing.h

```
#include "all_includes.h"


class Enclosing::PImpl
{
  int _ep;

  public:
  PImpl(int i) : _ep{i}
  {
    cout << "PImpl constr: " << _ep << endl;
  }

  friend Enclosing::Nested;
};


class Enclosing::Nested
{
  int _en;
  Enclosing* _ptr_enc;

  public:
  Nested(int i, Enclosing* p) : _en{i}, _ptr_enc{p}
  {
    cout << "Nested constr: " << _en << endl;
  }

  void acces()  // this function is my goal - I want to access a PImpl member from Nested
  {
    cout << "PImpl private member: " << _ptr_enc->_p->_ep << endl;
  }
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "all_includes.h"


int main()
{
  Enclosing* c = new Enclosing(17);
  //Enclosing::Nested n(22, c) ;   //comilator error: has initializer but incomplete type

  return 0;
}
```

Makefile

```
CC=g++
CCFLAGS=-std=c++14 -Wall

main: main.o enclosing.o
        ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} -o main main.o enclosing.o

main.o: main.cpp
        ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} -c main.cpp

class1.o: enclosing.cpp
        ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} -c enclosing.cpp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While compiling main(), compiler can't figure out the details of class Nested. This is because there is only a forward declaration of class available. How will the function signature be verified?
Try including the other header file.
This is what I get:

> ./main
> PImpl constr: 34
> Enclosing constr: 17
> Nested constr: 22

Comment: yes, a see, that in main is a problem and yesterday I really didn't :D thx